# lxml - ElementMaker: adding attributes

Tags: python, xml, lxml

let's assume the following code-snippet:

```
page = (
    E.html(
        E.head(
            E.title("This is a sample document")
        ),
        E.body(
            E.h1("Hello!", CLASS("title")),
            E.p("This is a paragraph with ", B("bold"), " text in it!"),
            E.p("This is another paragraph, with a ",
                A("link", href="http://www.python.org"), "."),
            E.p("Here are some reserved characters: <spam&egg>."),
            ET.XML("<p>And finally, here is an embedded XHTML fragment.</p>"),
        )
    )
)
```

Source: https://lxml.de/api/lxml.builder.ElementMaker-class.html

How can I add an attribute to the `<body>`-tag in the above syntax?
Doing something like this:

```
E.body(myattr="something",
```

couldn't solve my problem. So any hints are welcome!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47219957/407651

Answer (score 1):

I think you could define a new function as follows:

```
def ATTR(key, value):
    return {key: value}
```

and use it in E.body as follows:

....

```
E.body(ATTR('myattr', "something"),
    E.h1("Hello!", CLASS("title")),
    ...
```

hope this will solve your problem.